# Analyze weighted 2d points to figure out likely and unlikely locations for events

Tags: java, algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but I've spent a while trying to figure out what the best way to do this is, and everything I've come up with seems to take too long or be a bit unwieldy for the task.

So my problem is that I have a collection of weighted 2d points which represent guesses at the location of one or more events. There could be an arbitrary number of guesses and an arbitrary number of correct events (including 0). Guesses tend to be correct (although not exact), so if we mapped out the guesses, they would appear to be clustered around the correct events. However, there are also randomly placed outliers to add some noise.

Given this list of weighted points on a 2D plane, determine the most-likely location(s) of the events. The process to figure out the location of the events should be relatively fast, and any underlying data structure should allow the addition of more guesses on the fly. Also, figuring out every single event shouldn't be prioritized if it could mean incorrect locations being outputted, so outputting some sort of confidence bound for each event would be nice, although not required.

[image: example]

Here's a quick example I sketched up showing what I'm talking about. The circles represent the various guesses. The stars represent the correct locations I want the program to output.

I've thought of solving this problem myself in a couple of ways. First I tried to brute force it by iterating through every point and calculating the distance to every other point. If a point has k points within a given radius r, it is one of the correct locations. This seems like a pretty naive approach though, since the k points and r radius are arbitrary and could depend on the data. It also took quite a while to run. I thought of speeding it up with a kd tree and calculating the kth nearest neighbor, but it still has the same problems. My other attempt was using one of the various clustering algorithms, but I couldn't figure out how to adapt them to my use-case since I'm not really classifying points. I could be going about that the wrong way, though.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What do the weights have to do with anything?

Comment: Basically the guesses are given a weight based on other factors. A higher weight means a guess is more likely to be correct, although not by a large enough margin to determine anything by itself. Although the solution doesn't need to incorporate these (and should still work if the weights are all equal), I thought I'd add it in just in case they could be helpful.